# How to get the particular array node from JSON and print one by one using groovy?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, ready-api

I have the following JSON format :-

```
{
"id": "102",
"brand": "Disha",
"book": [{
    "slr": "EFTR",
    "description": "Grammer",
    "data": "TYR",
    "rate": true,
    "numberOfPages": 345,
    "maxAllowed": "12",
    "currentPage": 345
    },
    {
    "slr": "EFRE",
    "description": "English",
    "data": "TYR",
    "rate": true,
    "numberOfPages": 345,
    "maxAllowed": "12",
    "currentPage": 345
    },
    {
    "slr": "BGTR",
    "description": "French",
    "data": "TYR",
    "rate": true,
    "numberOfPages": 345,
    "maxAllowed": "12",
    "currentPage": 345
    }]
}
```

I want to write the groovy code to get the book array and print it one by one and before that I need to count the array node for book also.

I have tried below code:-

```
def response = context.expand( '${book#Response}' );
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
String inputJSON = slurper.parseText(response)
def strFinalValueToRead = "\$." + "book[0]"
def strActualValue = parse(inputJSON).read(strFinalValueToRead).toString()

log.info strActualValue
```

I am getting error as

> com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidJsonException: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected End Of File.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code works in my computer using the json provided by you.

Comment: I don't know, May be I am missing some external jar file for JSON. But I am not able to replicate this.

Comment: @Ashuans, see if my solution helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Script Assertion` for the same REST Request test step which can avoid another additional groovy step.

**Script Assertion**

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
log.info json.book
```

The above logs all the book details.

You may also use index to show a particular book details such as show book at 0 index.

```
log.info json.book[0]
```

It is also find certain book based on some filter. For instance, find a book whose `description` is `Grammer`.

```
log.info json.book.find {it.description == 'Grammer'}
```

Comment: Here, I am not confirm about the response I will be getting. The number of node for book or number of element in book array will be differing. So, In this case the above may not work. @Rao

Comment: Which part of the above does not work? Just showed a way to log 0th index. In order to display all the books, you do not need to write a for loop. Just look at the script assertion.

Comment: Oh., I mean if i'd have book array with undefined number of times which will be dynamic. And I want all of them to be printed.

Comment: Yes, `log.info json.book` does that. More over one **less** test step as `Script Assertion` is used with above approach. Appreciate upvotes for helpful answers and  if you think best answer, consider accepting as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

```
Map m = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
m.book.each{println it}
```

This is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after so much effort. I got the solution and tried it with Map and List.

```
Object inputJSON = slurper.parseText(response)

def countBook = inputJSON.book.size()

for(int i=0; i<countBook; i++) {
Map result = (Map) inputJSON
List bookNode = result.get("book")
log.info bookNode[i]    

}
```